# Edit details using GUID on hyperlink (non-nullable type System.Int32 error)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an  "non-nullable type System.Int32 error" when, i click on below hyperlink.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Student", new { id = item.Id },null)
```

**Class structure**

```
public class BasicInfo
{
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; } 
 .......
}
```

**Controller's view method**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  if (id != null)
  {
   //dbConnect's edit method return the records base on selected records
   //edit method calling store procedure to fetch records and return list
   return View("Edit", dbConnect.edit(ObjInfo));
  }
 return View();
}
```

if you see below screenshot then, you noticed that GUID is passing in URL but "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" not exist in the database.

As per my understanding, URL must be contain GUID which is store the database against respective record.

[image: got error after clicked on edit hyperlink]
[image: Table Structure]

let me know if more details are required

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanatory: you supplied a null value for `id`.  You have to figure out why.

Comment: i can't identify how its passing null value to ID? selected records contain GUID (id) value in database

Comment: The server must be interpreting `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` as a `null` GUID.  Try a different GUID; you're never going to see an all zeros GUID in your database anyway, unless you deliberately write one there.

Comment: Yes,Robert, I have tried with existing GUID value but its given me same error message.

Comment: Put a Debug.Print statement into your Edit method so that you can see what ID is being passed in.

Comment: @Beginners - you are using ...`Edit(int id)` - shouldnt it be ...`Edit(Guid id)`

Comment: yes, i know, i am getting null value in Edit method, but i dont know why its not contain any valid GUID in the URL after clicking on hyperlink. i want URL like "Student/Edit/2b4b4208-f072-4f06-afd5-8864b62a6b4a"

Comment: @JamesP, I have updated the Edit method to accepting guid as a parameter but still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a custom model binder as per [here](https://coderwall.com/p/_qzbkg/using-guid-as-parameter-in-your-mvc-actions):

> When you need have a parameter of the type Guid in your actions, is
>   needed the creation of a custom model binder. This is my custom
>   modelBinder:

```
public class GuidModelBinder : IModelBinder 
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var parameter = bindingContext
            .ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        return Guid.Parse(parameter.AttemptedValue);
    }
}
```

> Now, we need to register our custom modelBinder on startup of your application. We can make it so (in `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax.cs`):

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Guid), new GuidModelBinder());
```

> Thus our action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

> Ready! Now everything works like expected.